# Using Flask-SuperAdmin With SQLAlchemy-Utils ChoiceType

Tags: python-2.7, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-superadmin

I'm using [SQLAlchemy-Utils's ChoiceType](http://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data_types.html#module-sqlalchemy_utils.types.choice) in my project. I have installed [Flask-SuperAdmin](https://github.com/SyrusAkbary/Flask-SuperAdmin). I have configured admin as below:

```
admin = Admin(app)
admin.register(models.MyModel, session=db.session)
```

and model:

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
      type = db.Column(ChoiceType(MODEL_TYPES))
```

in admin section, when I try to save my model, I have an error:

```
ModelConversionError: Could not find field converter for type (<class 'sqlalchemy_utils.types.choice.ChoiceType'>).
```

Is this a right approach for using choices like "django choices"?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is the best way, but for the time being this is working for me.  (You can also ["scaffold"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13551851/450917) it.)
In the admin module:

```
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView

class MyModelAdmin(ModelView):
    form_choices = { 'type': MyModel.ENUM_NAME }
```